# is it possible to avoid the execution of a certain command?

Tags: bash

I have to avoid the execution of a certain command in  a bash script.
I thought to use a preexec trap to do so.

Let's say I want to avoid the command 'source' just for axample.
What I did is basically the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

function preexec ()
{
    if test $( echo "$BASH_COMMAND" | cut -d " " -f1 ) == "source"
        then
            echo ">>> do not execute this"
        else
            echo ">>> execute this"

    fi
}
trap 'preexec' DEBUG

echo "start"
source "source.sh"
echo "go on"

exit 0
```

the idea works fine, but at this point I don't know how to avoid the execution of said command.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Keep in mind that `source` is a shell builtin, unlike most of the other commands. Interesting question nevertheless.

Comment: my comment maybe stupid, but since you could change the script, why not just comment those  commands out and save? or the commands come from user input? you could check them by regex. or I didn't understand your requirement?

Comment: @Kent mine is just an easy example. what I need is to prevent the execution of a certain command under certain conditions which may occur or not.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround would be to define an alias for that command that does nothing and undefine it after the script has completed. The alias must be declared within the script itself for this to work:

```
alias source=:
## The actual script source here...
unalias source
```

Answer (score 1):

Redefine the `source` command by using a function called `source`.

Functions can be exported.

```
source() { builtin source /dev/null; return 0; }
source() { read < /dev/null; return 0; }
source() { :; return 0; }
export -f source
```

Comment: You don't need any commands, return is enough. `source() { return 1; }` might be best, to signal that the command didn't run successfully.